# How to make Devise return a subclass of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I have devise wich authenticates a user. `User` is split up into subclasses such as `User::AsProfile < User` or `User::AsRegistrant< User`. These are *not* Single Table Inheritance classes, just plain old ruby-objects that inherit from User.

I'd like devises' [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7df57d5081f9884849ca15e4fde179ef164a575f/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L58) helper to return an instance of User::AsProfile.

Unfortunately, Device has a lot of metaprogamming hidden away in `class_eval` so it is hard to understand what is going on.

Can I configure Devise to return another class (User::AsProfile) when running `current_user` in a controller?

Or must I override `current_user` in my controller to do so, and if so, how should I call warden to authenticate properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-implementing `current_user` in my ApplicationController.

Since I don't need the ability to have one user use multiple sessions, I could simplify the `current_user` a lot:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    return @current_user if @current_user
    current = warden.authenticate(scope: :user)
    @current_user = current.becomes(User::AsProfile) if current
  end
end
```

By using ActiveRecords [`becomes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes), the user is turned into a `User::AsProfile`. I'd rather not have this conversion and use `User::AsProfile#find` directly, but that seems only possible whith monkeypatching Warden.

As a sidenote: This problem shows well what happens when a library implements a poorly designed class-inheritance; or, in this case, no inheritance at all. The Devise code simply monkeypatches *your* ApplicationController and adds methods there. Never a good idea. With hindsight, Devise should simply be some modules (Concerns) that a developer can pick-and-choose and add to his controllers.

Comment: Have a look at [`sorcery`](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery). It still [does patch `ActionController::Base`](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/947cada5a79ada35559e1608a3a64aa54dd07ad6/lib/sorcery/engine.rb#L11) but it's much simpler/more open in most other aspects.